# Making WSO2 ESB Iterate Mediator Synchronous

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The below markup is my iterate mediator which is inside a proxy service set up within WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.

I'm attempting to loop through an array of form submissions and POST them into a RESTful API also defined within the ESB. However, even though I'm using the CALL mediator, the API logs show that all my iterate requests are firing milliseconds apart - which to me indicates that the iterate mediator is actually running my inline target sequence asynchronously despite setting **sequential="true"**.

Is there any way to ensure that the call to my REST API completes before iterating and submiting another request?

```
 <iterate continueParent="true"
          id="IterateRequestSink"
          expression="//*[local-name()='Submission']"
          sequential="true">
    <target>
       <sequence>
          <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
                    value="true"
                    scope="axis2"
                    type="STRING"/>
          <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
          <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
             <format>
                <params xmlns="">
                   <description>$1</description>
                   <return_call>$2</return_call>
                   <mobile>$3</mobile>
                   <sub_category>$4</sub_category>
                   <first_name>$5</first_name>
                   <last_name>$6</last_name>
                   <category>$7</category>
                </params>
             </format>
             <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='description']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='return_call']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='mobile']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='sub_category']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='first_name']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='last_name']/text()"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='category']/text()"/>
             </args>
          </payloadFactory>
          <property name="messageType"
                    value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    scope="axis2"
                    type="STRING"/>
          <call>
             <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:8280/crm/request" format="rest"/>
             </endpoint>
          </call>
          <log level="full"/>
       </sequence>
    </target>
 </iterate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using the call mediator and didn't realise there was an option for making the request blocking. This has resolved the concurrency issues.

**Edit**
In light of the comments below, this is the call mediator which solved the issue for me:

```
<call blocking="true">
  <endpoint>
    <address uri="http://localhost:8280/crm/request" format="rest"/>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

*Strangely enough this **isn't actually documented** in the latest WSO2 ESB documentation for the call mediator, which is a little unhelpful. But just look for the relevant drop down when in the mediator configuration UI or just set the option as above directly in the source.*

Comment: Fellow revieweres: this _is_ an answer, it's the OP telling what solved it for them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using callout[1][2] mediator instead of the call mediator. Callout mediator will do blocking external service invocations. And be mindful that usage of blocking service calls might affect the performance.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Callout+Mediator
[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+430%3A+Callout+Mediator+for+Synchronous+Service+Invocation

Comment: Thanks Sajith, but to clarify, call mediators can also be made blocking. I've figured out the blocking option.